# Ember component: bind-attr inside each

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have inherited an ember.js project from another team. So, I'm a total newbie.

I'm trying to render a list of objets and activate the object line when it's clicked.

I've created a component for the object listing but it's not working.

The jsbin bellow shows the approach I'm taking.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/muqiwiz/edit?html,js

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I recommend you read the whole [ember guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/).

The thing you need to do to get your demo working is: convert your javascript objects to Ember objects ([More info about the object model](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/))

Here's the working demo http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lejeci/edit?html,js,output